# Applicability of spreading to VLF, ELF communications

Tags: digital-communications

In a VLF (Very Low frequency) communication, I saw that FSK or differential type modulation like DPSK were used.

But is it possible to use spread spectrum communication with DPSK for VLF communication, it will improve transmission reliability? Has spread spectrum communications ever been used in the literature and if so what spreading sequence were used? Same questions for ELF (Extremely Low Frequency) communications.

Answer (score 1):

> But is it possible to use spread spectrum communication with DPSK for VLF communication, it will improve transmission reliability?

There's nothing speaking against that technically, but you will need to realize that your available bandwidth in VLF bands are in the low-double-digit kHz; that means if you have a spreading factor of $N$, you will only get $\frac 1N$ of that already very small bandwidth as symbol rate. And that might simply be too little to be useful, before the channel changes enough that you need to re-evaluate the channel.

The fact that existing schemes use differential modulations should tell you that with the little bandwidths that are available, taking time to sound the channel (e.g. with a preamble) will be very costly, and if that's the case, spreading your data will be undesirable.

> Same questions for ELF (Extremely Low Frequency) communications.

Same argument. Such techniques have certainly be used, especially since ELF is typically used for strategic command-to-submerged submarine communications ("we have been attacked, launch all your nuclear bombs"), and thus don't need much data rate.

Whether spreading is feasible depends on:

1. the ratio of bandwidth to the symbol rate you'll need to achieve to satisfy your application's data needs.
2. the time you can spend before the channel has changed enough to break the correlation with the spreading sequence (in case of DSSS) or the time the frequency selectivity of the channel stays constant enough to demodulate an FHSS system with sufficient reliability.

So, your question needs

1. a description of your available bands, especially w.r.t. bandwidths,
2. a description of your applications minimum necessary data rate, minimum and maximum packet sizes, maximum latency, and acceptable error probabilities
3. knowledge of the frequency selectivity of your channel, and the time it stays coherent

Armed with that, you can design a system that allows the receiver to estimate the channel (preambles, pilot symbols), and transmits data at the sufficient reliability. If you need more reliability, but have more data rate available than you need by a factor of at least 2, you can consider spreading – otherwise, you will need to look into whether your channel capacity allows for your application even theoretically, and if it does, your only way forward is channel coding, not spreading.